# PHP - Exploding each item in an array created by explode

Tags: php, arrays, loops, explode

My code is...

```
$string ="foo:bar,bar,bar|foo2:bar2,bar2,bar2";

$first_array = explode("|", $string);

function split(&$block) {

$block = explode(":", $block);

}

array_walk($first_array, "split");

echo $block["0"]["0"];
echo "<br />";
echo $block["0"]["1"];

?>
```

Thank you for the help thus far. From what I've gathered this should be the clean version of the supplied code. This does not echo anything, and neither does the code supplied.

Comment: $final_array is going to be an array of arrays. `echo $result` will just spit out the word `Array`, not the array's contents.

Comment: Maybe try using more sensible delimiters like `<delim1>` and `<delim2>` rather than `?!#@^&$%@#` and `&*%&@#*&^%` which you probably typed in manually and mistyped somewhere throwing it all off.

Comment: Also get your variable names consistent.  Is it `$city_array` or `$cityarray`...

Comment: *"I don't want to use a million columns and tables, so I would like to split my result"* Wait, you want to store relational data in a relational database, but you don't want to organize the data in a relational way? Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
$string ="foo:bar:bar:bar|foo2:bar2:bar2:bar2";

// first explode on |
$first_array = explode("|", $string);
// this function go on each lines of an array and transform each by a function
array_walk($first_array, function(&$item) {
         // so for each line explode with ':' as delimiter
         $item = explode(':', $item);
});

// To check all lines of the array
foreach($first_array as $line_array) {
     //my code for each sub-array
}

// To get only the last (second)
$second_sub = array_pop($first_array);

// if you want one dimension with all exploded you can use
// this function split with a regexp pattern
// "/[\|:,]+/" foreach "|" or ":" or ","  split the string
preg_split("/[\|:,]+/", $string);
```

Comment: Can you explain the syntax for me? Thank you!

Comment: I figured out the syntax. However, this is only half the battle. How do I pull the information from the second dimension of the array? Thanks.

Comment: just edited my code, with method to access each lines and method to get only the last

Answer (score 0):

Don't use $block since it's defined in another scope, moreover you cannot give "split" as a name for your function since it's an existing php function

```
$string ="foo:bar,bar,bar|foo2:bar2,bar2,bar2";

$first_array = explode("|", $string);

function mysplit(&$block) {

$block = explode(":", $block);

}

array_walk($first_array, "mysplit");

echo $first_array[0][0];
echo "<br />";
echo $first_array[0][1];
```